# Why Spring JPA is not able to create repository and throwing No property 'empty' found for type 'UserRef

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, repository

I am trying to create a Repository by having @embeddable and Embedded ID .

```
public class UserRef {  

  @EmbeddedId
  private UserRefId id;  
}
```

and

```
public class UserRefId implements Serializable {

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "USER_TYPE_CD")
  private String userTypeCd; 

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "USER_INTERNAL_CD")
  private String userInternalCd; 
}
```

When I am trying to run my application class its throwing:

```
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Failed to create query for method public abstract repository.UserRefRepository.findById(java.lang.String) !  No property 'empty' found for type 'UserRef'
```

This is my repository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRefRepository extends JpaRepository <UserRef, UserRefId> { 
  public Map<String, Map<String, String>>  findById (String refTypeCd); 
}
```

I tried changing camelCase too but its not working at all, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo, but your example here is missing `@Embeddable` on `UserRefId`.

Comment: its a typo ,@Embeddable  is there

Comment: sorry but got the error ,its throwing error because of return type .It is resolved now .